# Can't replace "\" with "/"

Tags: python, replace, str-replace

I am trying to replace a string here in Python.

This is my Input -

```
link = (r"C:\dell\Documents\Ms\Realm")
```

I want my output to be like this:

```
C:/dell/Documents/Ms/Realm
```

I tried the replace method it didn't work.

the code tried:

```
link = (r"C:\dell\Documents\Ms\Realm")
link.replace("\","/")
```

Comment: Why? The normal Windows path works just fine. If you want to improve anything, use `pathlib` instead of raw strings. As for why your code fails, Stackoverflow's and your editors syntax highlighting show what's wrong. `\"` is an escape sequence used to insert double quotes into strings. What SO shows right now is a green string `"\","` followed by `/` and the unterminated string `")`

Comment: if you trying to get a absolute path then use pathlib as panagiotis mentioned above. **from pathlib import Path** then **print(Path("C:\dell\Documents\Ms\Realm"))**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python strings, the backslash "\" is a special character, also called the "escape" character. You need to add second backslash to "escape" it and use in string search.

```
link.replace("\\", "/")
```

Comment: For everybody... if you are facing a problem that as anything to do with backslashes, just duplicate them. That solves 90% of the problems.

Comment: @FLAK-ZOSO better yet, eliminate the problem by not having to use them

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with that Windows path. There's no reason to replace anything. A real improvement would be to use [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) instead of raw strings:

```
from pathlib import Path
link = Path(r"C:\dell\Documents\Ms\Realm")
```

That would allow you to construct paths from parts using, eg [joinpath](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.joinpath), get the parts of the path with `parts`, the name with `name`, directory with `parent` etc.

```
var filePath=link.joinpath("some_file.txt")
print(filePath)
-------------------
C:\dell\Documents\Ms\Realm\some_file.txt
```

and more

```
>>> print(link.parts)
('C:\\', 'dell', 'Documents', 'Ms', 'Realm')
>>> print(link.parent)
C:\dell\Documents\Ms
```

Or search for files in a folder recursively:

```
var files=(for file in link.rglob("*.txt") if file.is_file())
```